# Trigger on radio-button set via click event?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Im trying to fire a trigger on a radio button, but cant get it to work.
It works fine if i use a checkbox instead, but i kinda need the radio button.

The radio button can be set by pressing it, or the Test div. If the radio button is changed it should fire the trigger.

```
<div class="testing">  
  <div class="test">Test</div>
  <input type="radio">
</div>

$(".test").on("click", function() {
var radio = $(this).closest(".testing").find("input[type='radio']");
    if (!radio.prop("checked")) {
        radio.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        radio.prop("checked", false);
    }
})

  $(".testing").on("change", function() {
  $(".test").html("weee");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fbmod5ca/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trigger('change')` to trigger event explicitly

```
radio.prop("checked", true).trigger('change');
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbmod5ca/1/)